# Getting 401 Error with SignalR Owin Host 2.0.3

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I am trying to setup a load test exercising as much of the code base as possible. I am running the server and client in the same process:

```
class Program 
{
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            });
        }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var signalr = "http://localhost:21337/";

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(signalr))
        {
            var connection = new HubConnection(signalr) {Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials};

            var catalog = connection.CreateHubProxy("CatalogHub");

            connection.Start().Wait();

            catalog.Invoke("SendChat", String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

However, on `connection.Start.Wait()` I get a 401 Unauthorized error. I am not sure why because IIS is nowhere in the pipeline.

Comment: Have you tried running the "client" code in a separate process first? You may have something else misconfigured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PEBKAC. Turns out the hub has `[Authorize]` set on it but I was using anonymous authentication. Ensuring Ntlm authentication fixed the problem.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties[typeof(HttpListener).FullName];
            listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJSONP = true
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after I set the Authorize attribute on my hub class and found out that Windows Authentication was disabled in the properties for my Web API project. This was pointed out in [getting 401 error with signalr owin host 2.0.3](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana). This worked perfectly when I enabled it and I was also able to get the User Identity Name in my hub

One thing to note is that I did not have to set the Authentication scheme as mentioned in the above post